# Can't start service with Docker Version 4.11.0 (83626)

Tags: laravel, docker, laradock

Could anyone help me, I have a problem with Docker's new version that I just updated,

and here is the error message after I run command to start the service,

Note: I use laradock with the Docker

```
WARN[0000] The "lXaL3lj6raFic6rFqr2" variable is not set. Defaulting to a blank string. 
Invalid template: "admin:$2y$10$lXaL3lj6raFic6rFqr2.lOBoCudAIhB6zyoqObNg290UFppiUzTTi"
gms-admin@kosakayuudais-MacBook-Pro laradock %
```

[image]
Please help me I appreciate

Answer (score 14):

That's happen on `TRAEFIK_DASHBOARD_USER` at `.env` file which is the value contains `$` character. And docker recognized it as variable, that's why we found **The "lXaL3lj6raFic6rFqr2" variable is not set** error message.

You could pull the latest update from Laradock which add quotation for `TRAEFIK_DASHBOARD_USER` variable on `.env.example` file or just manually add single quote on `TRAEFIK_DASHBOARD_USER` variable.

Comment: Hi @Aksal thanks for the help. Didn't expect to meet you again here . (PetengDedet)

Comment: Wkwk. My pleasure, @glam

Answer (score 0):

In docker desktop you can disable docker-compose under the "Experimental Features" section. Most probably you are using the version that is in beta for now. You can check your version with `docker-compose --version`. And try to switch it back to older version.

Try to stay away anything that is in beta version or just released.

May be helpful: [Check out](https://github.com/chaintope/workshop202107/commit/4db7fe0b764c95f4659000c31b2c138a12c0a361)

If none of them helps, try to reinstall docker